# How to solve moment generating function for attaining probability?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, moment-generating-function

Mx(t) = 1/216*(5+e^t)^3                 t€R
 Then P(X>1)=?

The far I got it is that..It coincides with the mgf of binomial distribution and after comparing we get......
 q=5.     p=1.      n=3. 
  Don't know how to look for probability.

Comment: ... what is this $q$, $p$, and $n$?  The binomial only has two parameters...  and if it is the MGF of a binomial, don't you already know how to calculate $p(x>1)$ for a binomial variate?

Comment: @jbowman The OP ignores the $1/216=6^{-3}$. By including it we may write $$M_X(t)=\left(\frac{5}{6}+\frac{1}{6}e^t\right)^3=(q+p e^t)^n$$ for $q=5/6, p=1/6, n=3$. This is the mgf of a Binomial$(3, 1/6)$ distribution.

Comment: Demon: see the questions on computing Binomial probabilities at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+probability.

Comment: @whuber I was exactly looking for this-   P(X>1)=1-P(X<=1)=1-(P(X=0)+P(X=1)) and due to your evaluation of parameters it turns out to be 2/27 and this is the right answer.Thanku so much.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).